# What does "vote with" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Barack and Hillary agreed on most issues. But she had **voted with** President Bush to go to war in Iraq.

Bold part, What does "vote with" mean??
It doesn't appear in the dictionary.

Comment: Think "traveled with", "ate with", "drove with", and "laughed with".  It's a similar concept.

Comment: @RonJohn thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... But she had **voted with President Bush** to go to war in Iraq. [emphasis added]

*With* takes [sense 3b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with)

> used as a function word to **express agreement** or sympathy

OP's example means Hillary had **voted in agreement with** President Bush to go to war in Iraq.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer!

Comment: It is more like "had voted **with President Bush** to go" than "had **voted with** President Bush to go"

Comment: @Peter Good point, thanks for reply.

Comment: @Peter, yes, you're right.   Thx